# How to better count occurrences of a list in another list and then list the results for each element using count

Tags: python, pandas, list, count

I want a `faster` way for Pandas python to calculate number of occurrences of each element of `listA` in `listB` and make the number of counts into `listC`. for example

```html
listA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

listB = [1,1,5,4,8,3,4,7,9,2,1,4,7,6,2,4,5,6,3]

output:

listC = [3,2,2,4,2,2,2]
```

The number 1 appears 3 times, and 2 appears three times so on. This is just an example in my real work `listA` has `800 000` elements and `listB` has `2million` elements. I am using the following code but it takes too long to process using Pandas.

```html
listC =[listB.count(x) for x in listA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to speed up the task:

```
from collections import Counter

listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
listB = [1, 1, 5, 4, 8, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3]

c = Counter(listB)

listC = [c.get(v) for v in listA]
print(listC)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

Or: Use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy.bincount):

```
count_arr = np.bincount(listB)
print([count_arr[x] for x in listA])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I cant upvote your answer because I still have a reputation lesser than 15. The solution worked. But just to ask, it seems only to work when elements in the list are integers. Is there a provision for where elements are strings?

Comment: Is collections.Counter  better than a simple `c = {}` .. `for k in listB: c[k] = c.get(k, 0) + 1`? Internal implementation of `collections.Counter` does the same, right?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh it is equivalent, but the `Counter(iterable)` operation is optimized in C-level code.

Comment: @Moshe no, it works as long as the elements are hashable. It certainly works with both `int` and `str` objects. You are going to have to elaborate on what, exactly, "doesn't work" means

Comment: Anyway, I think `c[v]` is more appropriate, since `Counter` objects will return `0` if it hasn't been seen automatically, instead, if you use `.get` it will return `None`, and `0` probably makes more sense in a counting context

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/072ec69af592611f36349f5048569ab7e72b8b61/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L519) looks like the source code for `collections.Counter`, it's written in python. How do they optimise this code?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh if you look closely, it [imports an optimized implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7a041162468b83f6cad667b78ed5c786286aed2b/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L510).  This is what is used in the [overridend `.update`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7a041162468b83f6cad667b78ed5c786286aed2b/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L636). And [here is the correspodning C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7a041162468b83f6cad667b78ed5c786286aed2b/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L2306)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Thanks a lot. Had this confusion for long time.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh that is a very common pattern in the CPython standard library, there is a pure python version that will try to import an optimized C implementation, defaulting to the Python implementation if it doesn't exist. It *will* exist in any standard CPython distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the idea to sort that huge data is out of the question?

Just that I think count() might work faster *maybe* if the data is sorted, because similar values are placed in adjacent position.

Comment: I guess it can work but i need a universal method that can also be used for strings. and I guess sorting out strings is quite difficult